# Installing tensorflow-gpu on CentOS 6.8

Tags: python, centos, tensorflow

**System Information**

OS: CentOS 6.8
Python: 2.7.11

**Problem**

Hi all, I would like to install tensorflow. Since I am using CentOS 6.8, it seems there is not official way to install tensoflow. Therefore, I googled for several ways to install it, and I followed this guide: https://blog.abysm.org/2016/06/building-tensorflow-centos-6/
(Other guides didn't work for me, some are glibc problem, some are "not a support wheel" problem, etc.)

However, now I would like to use GPU to accelerate. I have installed cuda and cudnn, but when I tried to build tensorflow with gpu in a way similar to the guide mentioned above(in the ./configure step I chose "enable cuda"), I got errors like this:

```
[root@Linux1 tensorflow]# ~/bin/bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/a3c166d17dc24b80d65cd498892a86b2/external/protobuf/BUILD:609:1: Linking of rule '@protobuf//:python/google/protobuf/internal/_api_implementation.so' failed: link_dynamic_library.sh 
failed: error executing command external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/link_dynamic_library.sh no ignored ignored ignored 
external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc -shared -o ... (remaining 10 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '-plugin'
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 14.665s, Critical Path: 2.62s
```

I am new to linux, and I have no idea what's going on. Is there possible way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run all the instructions, including ./configure?

Comment: Yes, I followed all the instructions. A little modification is that instead of "~/bin/bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package", I ran "~/bin/bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package" to install the gpu version.

Comment: To use --config=cuda you need to set it up at ./configure time